# Validation Exception using DynamoDB and Amazon API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

hi I keep getting a validation exception error:

"__type": "com.amazon.coral.validate#ValidationException",
  "message": "1 validation error detected: Value null at 'key' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must not be null"

I have also attached what my application/json mapping template looks like.

```
{ 
"TableName": "Comments",
"Items": {
    "commentid": {
        "S": "$input.path('$.commentid')"
        },
    "pageid": {
        "S": "$input.path('$.pageid')"
        },
    "userName": {
        "S": "$input.path('$.userName')"
    },
    "message": {
        "S": "$input.path('$.message')"
    }
}
```

}

Thank You

Comment: Hey, Can you share the schema for your problem table?
Not clear how you configured composite key of the table.

Comment: so the table name is Comments, primary key is commentid, the the other columns are message, pageid, and userName. There is also a pageid-index.

Comment: So I was actually able to solve the issue, I had called the Action "GetItem" instead of "PutItem" in the POST Integration Request of Amazon API Gateway

Comment: Ahh, glad to hear you've solved it :) Thanks for your update